# Foreach $wpdb->insert inserting blank rows

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Trying to add rows from textarea to MySql database, but just last row inserting correctly all other rows inserting empty

```
$model = 'MacBook Pro';
$lines = explode("\n", $textarea);

foreach ($lines as $model_number) {
      $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('model'=>$model,   'model_number'=>$model_number));
```

var_dump ($model_number) returning:

```
 string(6) "A4348 " string(6) "A3412 " string(5) "A8495"
```

MySql rows:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------------+
                          |
                           |
| 87 | MacBook Pro | A8495                            |
+----+-------------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can see is the length of the string. It is possible that you have a restriction on your DB to only allow say 5 characters to be inserted into the table. Secondly there could be a restriction that the space at the end of the string vioolates.

I would simply change this:

```
$rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('model'=>$model,   'model_number'=>$model_number));
```

To this and see if this works, other than this I am stumped and see no issue.

```
$rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('model'=>$model,   'model_number'=>str_replace(" ","",$model_number)));
```